# how to add tab bar in navigation based application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a project of Navigation based application. Now I want to put tab bar on it and add some more screens and actions on that tab bar. So should I create a Window based application and add code of both (i.e tab bar and navigation based application). Or is there anyway to customized the same project (i.e navigationbased application) and add tab bar on it and those screens that are needed.

Please tell me the best possible ansr for it. Or if you have any tutorial or any sample project that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tabbar controller in navigationController. It is similar to add like how you push UIViewController in UINavigationController, just difference is here you are pushing UITabBarController. Offcourse you should know how to create tabbarcontroller for that.

Comment: So, can u provide me any tutorial link to know how to do this. and how  my appdelegate class will look.

Comment: Check this link- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html